# Fastest algorithm for set of two people to marry eachother

Tags: algorithm, graph

I can't think of an algorithm for this problem.The problem is:
There are two sets, set "M" contains List of men, set "F" contains a list of women.

Now there is a set "Marriage" which contains permitted marriages, suppose `(a,1)` would mean that it is possible for man `a` to marry woman `1` and woman `1` to marry man `a`.

Marriages can only be done if partner matches from recommended list. We call it "Success" if from each man from `M` it is possible to marry someone from the recommended list corresponding to their name, and same for woman from List `F`. Else we call it "unsuccessful"

---

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
List M = {a,b,c,d}
List F= {1,2,3,4}
Recommended List = { (a,1),(a,4),(b,1),(b,2),(c,3),(c,4),(d,1),(d,4) }
```

`a` can marry `1`, `b` can marry `2`, `c` can marry `3`, `d` can marry `4`. 
Output = "Sucess"

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
List M = {a,b,c,d} 
List F= {1,2,3,4}
Recommended List = { (a,1),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2),(c,3),(c,1),(d,1),(d,2) }
```

It isn't possible to marry woman `4` because there is no pair possible in the recommended list which has woman `4` as her partner.

Output = "Unsucessful"

---

I need the fastest possible algorithm to determine success or unsuccess

Comment: Nice question!! Show your code till now

Comment: Just need the algorithm, no coding here ( as my tags specify)

Comment: `each women is given recommendations to one of y men` (at least/most/exactly one?) `EXAMPLE 2 … It isn't possible to marry woman 4 because it isn't in the recommended list` (Try using a spelling (&grammar) checker.)

Comment: Your problem is a matching problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory). Specifically in bipartite graphs.

Comment: I'd have a look here: http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_guide/graph_algorithms/maxcard_bipartite_matching.html. Your "Marriage" constraint just means there are less edges in the bipartite graph...

Comment: No full algorithm, but you could just try backtracking, always trying the individual with the fewest possibilities first. If `a` is only in pair `(a,1)`, then `a` has to marry `1`; remove all pairs that have either `a` or `1` and repeat; if all are married, success, if one has zero possibilities, then backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems graph matching (stable marriage) problem, but it can be easily solved as follows.

```
r_f=[i[1] for i in recomended_list]
r_m = [i[0] i in recomended_list] 
answer = "successfull" if set(M).issubset(r_m) and set(F).issubset(r_f) else "unsucessfull"
```

Comment: This only checks whether each male and female have someone in the "recommended list", but not if e.g. two males are interested in the same female, and no one else, or am I missing something here?

Comment: yeh, its definitely not stable matching problem. Because there is no such thing as preferences for both men and women

Comment: @tobias_k the question asks wherether a List_m orList_F contains only elements from the recomended list, i.e. i interpret it as whether each item in the list has someone interested in them.

Answer (score 0):

Let create clusters, like this:

M1 = All men having a single match

M2 = All men having two matches

W1 = All women having a single match

...

Now, you find all matches from M1 and W1 (trivial matches) and take them out of the set. Now, let's plan the pairs of the lowest gravity (man cluster index + women cluster index is a minimum) and backtrack them. Handle the sub-cases just as you handled the main case.