# Using graph theory for fusion of two elements

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I need the fastest possible algorithm for such a problem. I think we gotta use graphs here. **This is not a help with coding but the algorithm.**

Basically, we are given two lists of elements. Those two lists are alpha-List and num-List. Then we are also given a list of fusions called fusion-List which where each element is possible fusions. The aim is to find the max number of fusions possible by combining any element of alpha-List and num-List. We can only fuse those two elements if and only if the combination exists in the fusion-List.

Constraints: Each element of alpha-List and num-List can fuse only once. None of the elements can fuse with element of its own list. Fusion only possible if and only if the fusion is listed in the fusion-List.

Example:

alpha-List{ a, b, c, d}
num-List {1, 2, 3, 4}

fusion-List {   (a,1), (a,2), (a,4), (b,4), (d,3)  }

Output: Max possible fusions are - 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest algorithm for set of two people to marry eachother](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105764/fastest-algorithm-for-set-of-two-people-to-marry-eachother)

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple matching problem in a bipartite graph, see for example [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs). The first set of vertices is the alpha-List, the second one is the num-List, and the edges are the fusion-List.